# Passing JSONArray from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

While passing JsonArray from one Activity to a Fragment,

> it raises an error inflating a fragment,which was worked before adding
>   this code

Activity

```
public static NotificationNews setArgs(String json_arr,int count){
        NotificationNews nf = new NotificationNews();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("json_arr",json_arr);
        args.putInt("count",count);
        nf.setArguments(args);
        return nf;
    }
```

Fragment

```
Bundle args=getArguments();
        try {
            JSONArray json_arr =new JSONArray(args.getString("json_arr"));
            prepare_data(json_arr,args.getInt("count"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

can anyone tell whats wrong with this code

Comment: Is the error inflating a fragment caused by exception being thrown? Can you post the stack trace.

Comment: Post the fragment code. We don't know how is called that method